# Laravel 5.4 using old controller in controllers directory

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working on an application in which i created backup of a controller in the controllers directory. Now application is using that backup controller even its name is different and i am not using it in routes->web.php file. I am facing this issue on live server not on localhost. Please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Sounds like cached controllers. Tray it out:  `artisan cache:clear; artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I run this command and it solved my problem.

```
composer dump-autoload
```